# Appcelerator can't deploy to any device

Tags: android, macos, appcelerator

I have installed and configured Appcelerator and the android SDK on mac High Sierra, I can see my device through the command

```
adb devices
```

But in the Appcelerator Studio the device doesn't show to deploy, I only have the option Android device and Android Emulator and not the device name. When I choose android device the Studio returns a Error saying that no Android devices connected.

Here is the relevant part of the appc info command

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2018, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.13.3
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8.0GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 8.9.1
  npm Version                 = 5.5.1

Appcelerator CLI
  Installer                   = 4.2.12
  Core Package                = 7.0.2

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.41

Titanium SDKs
  7.0.2.GA
    Version                   = 7.0.2
    Install Location          = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.0.2.GA
    Platforms                 = iphone, android
    git Hash                  = 5ef0c56
    git Timestamp             = 2/9/2018 19:05
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.43
  6.3.0.GA
    Version                   = 6.3.0
    Install Location          = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.3.0.GA
    Platforms                 = iphone, android, mobileweb
    git Hash                  = 3620088
    git Timestamp             = 11/1/2017 01:20
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.43

Mac OS X
  Command Line Tools          = installed

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Version                     = 1.8.0_131
  Java Home                   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

Genymotion
  Path                        = not found
  Genymotion Executable       = not found
  Genymotion Player           = not found
  Home                        = not found

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = not found
  Version                     = unknown

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
  SDK Path                    = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/android-sdk-macosx

Android NDK
0NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  1) android-23
    Name                      = Android 6.0
    API Level                 = 23
    Revision                  = 3
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = 
    Path                      = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-23
  2) android-26
    Name                      = Android 8.0.0 (not supported by Titanium SDK 7.0.2.GA, but may work)
    API Level                 = 26
    Revision                  = 1
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
    ABIs                      = 
    Path                      = /Users/rodrigofelga/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-26

Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  None

Genymotion Emulators
  None

Connected Android Devices
SM-T116BU
  ID                          = 3004086317342300
  State                       = device
  SDK Version                 = 4.4.4 (android-19)
  ABIs                        = armeabi, armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: I'm able to deply to device using the appc run -p android -T device command, but the device still don't show on the run dropdown of the studio

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

- Just to be sure: Is your phone in developer mode and USB debugging enabled? ([check here](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/))
- Android NDK is not installed ([check/download here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html))
- You can also try to install one or more Android Emulator(s) and debug your app (not the fastest way to do but it works). Go to `Preferences` > `Studio` > `Platforms` > `Android` > `Manage AVDs`.

Comment: * The device has USB debugging enable
* Android NDK is not required
* The problem is not with emulator and only with real devices

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by installing the API 25 and SDK 6.2.2 and the device appeared on Appcelerator Studio